# Browser is not sending the cookie with fetch, allthough server and frontend have the same ip address (but different ports)

Tags: cookies, browser, fetch, setcookie, samesite

Ialready tried many things, but the browser still refuses to set the Cookie header on any request I make in the frontend. Both server and frontend running on my local machine.

I created a hosts entry and enabled port forwarding.

So api-v3-dev:5177 is the frontend and api-v3-dev:3000 is the backend.

I dynamically set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the request's origin.

After successfull login, I see a responses header like

```
set-cookie: token=eyJoZTUiLCJpZCI6; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://api-v3-dev:5177
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, Set-Cookie, Cookie, Origin, X-Requested-With, Bearer, Accept
```

When I do another fetch request with like:

```
 const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include'
    };
 fetch('http://api-v3-dev:3000/whoami', requestOptions);
```

Since it is locally, I cannot set Secure & SameSite=None.

But everthing I read about cookies and sameSite tells, that it is not like the Origin in Cors and it indeed treats both different subdomains and different ports as the same site, so it should also work with sameSite=Lax for http connections.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser receives the `token=eyJoZTUiLCJpZCI6` cookie with the HTTP response but does not store it, because it violates the following [validity requirement](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/cookiemonster/):

> The domain of the cookie must be .local or a subdomain of a public suffix (see http://publicsuffix.org/ --also known as an extended Top Level Domain).

The hostname `api-v3-dev` defined in your `hosts` file ends with neither `.local` nor a public suffix. (Nor is it `localhost`, which would also work.)

And since the cookie is not stored in the browser, it is not sent with any subsequent request either.

Strangely, if a cookie is received with an HTTPS response, it is set even if the rule given above is violated. At least that is the behavior I observed with Google Chrome.

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing that out.
Unfortunatelly it still does not work.

Origin:
http://api-v3.local:5177

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
http://api-v3.local:5177


I also tried .com and .de.

The server is running inside WSL and the website on the host WIN PC but I dont think thats the problem I can connect successfully to the api via postman or to unprotected routes in the browser, login does also work